# exctractvalue from xmltype / soap oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype, extract-value

i need to get "ineedthis" value from field

```
REQUEST_INFO:
...

<s:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<X-dynaTrace xmlns="http://ns.dynatrace.com/wcf" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">FW3;-1003312095;1;-56375709;115092;0;975784079;78</X-dynaTrace>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<storeContract xmlns="xxx/integration">
<storeRequest>
<contract>
<contractSeries>ineedthis</contractSeries>

select extractvalue(XMLType(sap.REQUEST_INFO),'s/s/storeContract/storeRequest/contract/contractSeries')
from sap
```

cant get the value

Comment: Without knowing the complete structure of your XML, it's hard to identify the right path for `extractValue`. Can you please post a complete [simplified] XML?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to extract the path

```
s/s/storeContract/storeRequest/contract/contractSeries
```

but your SOAP response doesn't have any nodes called `s`; it has nodes called Envelope, Header and Body in the *namespace* `s`. So you potentially want the path:

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body/storeContract/storeRequest/contract/contractSeries
```

which on its own gets an `LPX-00601: Invalid token` error because it doesn't know what `s:` is. You can supply the namespaces with the third argument:

```
select extractvalue(XMLType(sap.request_info),
  '/s:Envelope/s:Body/storeContract/storeRequest/contract/contractSeries',
  'xmlns="xxx/integration" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"'
  ) as contractseries
from sap;
```

or the lazy way is to wildcard the namespace and only identify the final node you want:

```
select extractvalue(XMLType(sap.request_info),'//*:contractSeries') as contractseries
from sap;
```

But `extractvaue` is deprecated so it's better to use XMLQuery - still being lazy:

```
select XMLQuery('//*:contractSeries/text()'
  passing XMLType(sap.request_info)
  returning content) as contractseries
from sap;
```

or with explicit namespaces:

```
select XMLQuery('
    declare default element namespace "xxx/integration";
    declare namespace s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    /s:Envelope/s:Body/storeContract/storeRequest/contract/contractSeries/text()'
  passing XMLType(sap.request_info)
  returning content) as contractseries
from sap;

CONTRACTSERIES                
------------------------------
ineedthis
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b7f1829071eeef3f71a8aa96bc75bc3b)